# Django datefield in a model form is generated in html with type=text rather than type=date

Tags: python, django, forms, datefield

here is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import DateTimeInput, DateInput
from property.models import PropertyView

class DetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PropertyView
        
        datepurchased = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'])
        fields = ['address1', 'address2','postcode','datepurchased']
```

and here is how the form appears:
[form with text instead of date input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3HXz.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom widget:

```
from django.forms.widgets import DateInput


class MyDateInput(DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
```

and then plug in this custom widget

```
class DetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    datepurchased = forms.DateField(
        input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'], widget=MyDateInput
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PropertyView
        fields = ['address1', 'address2', 'postcode', 'datepurchased']
```

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found the solution for this. If I include a widget in the form as follows:

```
widgets = {'datepurchased': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})}
```

This has the effect of enforcing the input type to 'date'.
However, I am still wondering why this is necessary. Surely the fact that it is a date field should be enough for django to give it the right input type? Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh, and apologies to Willem, I wrote this before I saw your answer. It looks like you have given me a similar solution but in a more structured way!

Comment: Django simply uses `'text'` as type by definition: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/widgets/#dateinput Likely because `type="date"` is still experimental (some browsers still don't seem to support it effectively, and furthermore often not a good idea, a `type="number"` has some similar problems: https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/12/26/why-the-number-input-is-the-worst-input/)